# Integrating JMeter with Cucumber+Ruby+Selenium framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, jmeter, cucumber-junit

We have a BDD framework built in Selenium + Cucumber + Ruby which we use for functional testing. Is it possible to integrate JMeter with these scripts ?

Comment: What do you mean by integrating? Are you referring to calling the '.jmx' file from Ruby?

Comment: no we don't want to create.jmx files, By integrating I mean we want to use our existing selenium functional testcases for load test.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid use of cucumber/ruby/selenium. This whole setup is meant to imitate a real user and so should wait for the page to load etc etc. With load testing you can end up blatting huge amounts of information through which would be unrealistic for a real user to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [ruby-jmeter](https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter) gem? It should be as simple as follows:

```
test do
  threads count: 10 do
    visit name: 'Example Domain', url: 'http://example.com'
  end
end.run(
  path: 'c:/JMeter/bin/',
  file: 'test.jmx',
  log: 'jmeter.log',
  jtl: 'test.jtl')
```

If you don't have possibility to install/use jmeter-ruby gem JMeter is Java-based application so Cucumber full integration isn't something you can easily get (unless you're using [Cucumber-JVM](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Cucumber-JVM) but it is still possible

JMeter can be launched as [a command-line non-GUI application](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) just like any other external command from Ruby as follows:

```
`jmeter -n -t /path/to/script.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl`
```

or

```
%x(jmeter -n -t /path/to/script.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl)
```

You can switch JMeter results format to xml (it defaults to CSV) and parse XML results to define pass/fail criteria. Results output format is controlled via `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format` property which can be uncommented and set in *jmeter.properties* file, overriden in *user.properties* file (both live under /bin folder of your JMeter installation) or provided as a command-line argument via -J key as

```
%x(jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t /path/to/script.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl)
```

Comment: I think with ruby-jmeter gem we can only convert our jmeter testplan written in ruby to .jmx file, but our requirement is to load test our existing selenium script, like we do for framework build in java-selenium.

Comment: Ok, now I got your point. Currently it's not possible to "convert" selenium tests into JMeter, however you can run your selenium tests through JMeter's proxy which will record your test flow. After recording you should be able to replay the test with high number of virtual users

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T for your response.Btw we want to achieve something like this http://intensetesting.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/integrating-jmeter-with-selenium-code/  but unlike this we have have cucumber-ruby in our framework.

Comment: If having multithreaded selenium tests is what you're looking for I believe that combination of JSR223 sampler and JRuby should fit. However I would rather go for Selenium Grid in that case